# How do I trigger an event function nested in another event function on React?

Tags: reactjs, events, nested, react-hooks, onchange

I am trying to find an efficient way to write functions without creating duplicates like this.

```
const InputChange = (initialValue, validateInputChange = false, validate) => {

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target; // <- Target Name and Value
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleValidation = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target; // <- Same Target Name and Value
    if (validateInputChange) {
      validate({ [name]: value });
    }
  };

  return {
    values,
    setValues,
    handleInputChange,
    errors,
    setErrors,
    handleValidation,
  };

};
```

What I am trying to accomplish is stacking these two functions without having to pass the same target `name` and `value` twice, like this.

```
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target; // <- Target Name and Value Passed Once
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
    const handleValidation = (event) => {
      if (validateInputChange) {
        validate({ [name]: value });
      }
    };
  };
```

How I am triggering these event: `onChange={ handleInputChange }` and `onBlur={ handleValidation }`

```
<TextField
   name="name"
   label="Name"
   value={values.name}
   onChange={handleInputChange}
   onBlur={handleValidation} // <- This is not working: onBlur={handleInputChange(handleValidation)}?
   error={errors.name}
 />
```

How do I trigger an event function nested in another event function on React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a curried helper function that accepts an event handler, and prepares the data for it.

The `handleEventValue` is a curried utility function, that accepts a handler, and returns a function that accepts and event object. It then invokes the handler, and passed it the prepare `{ [name]: value }` object. You should define this function outside of your component / custom hook.

```
const handleEventValue = handler => ({ target: { name, value } }) => handler({ [name]: value });
```

Usage:

```
const handleInputChange = handleEventValue(val => {
  setValues({
    ...values,
    ...val
  });
});

const handleValidation = handleEventValue(val => {
  if (validateInputChange) {
    validate(val);
  }
});
```

Example:

```js
const handleEventValue = handler => ({ target: { name, value } }) => handler({ [name]: value });

const Example = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({ x: '', y: '' });
  
  const handleInputChange = handleEventValue(val => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      ...val
    });
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <input name="x" value={values.x} onChange={handleInputChange} />
      
      <input name="y" value={values.y} onChange={handleInputChange} />
      
      <div>x: {values.x} y: {values.y}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome. That works too! It will clean as I continue to create more event functions. Thanks. :)